# cargar elemento html con id

Tags: javascript, html

tengo que cambiar una lista `html` desde `javascript`. mi código es

```
document.getElementById("my_element").innerHTML = "<li id="my_li">...</li>";
```

Aparentemente funciona correctamente y el bloque carga perfectamente, pero sin el id.

```
document.getElementById("my_li") // devuelve NULL
```

Que está pasando?

edición: ese es mi código, el problema sigue

```
document.getElementById("my_element").innerHTML = '<li id="my_li">...</li>';
```

Comment: Nicolás, por favor añadir  el código completo, debería funcionar con la última edición.

Answer (score 2):

No puedes usar comillas dobles en la cadena que estas encerrando con las mismas, te explico, lo correcto seria:

```
document.getElementById("my_element").innerHTML = '<li id="my_li">.../li>';
```

o

```
document.getElementById("my_element").innerHTML = "<li id=\"my_li\">.../li>";
```

Cualquiera de los 2 ejemplos te funcionara.

En virtud que no dejas mucho código para revisar donde estas cometiendo el error no me queda mas que dejarte algunos ejemplos de como hacerlo.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo hecho con jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("button").on("click",function () {
  $("ul").html('\
   <li id="My_li_a">lista a</li>\
   <li id="My_li_b">lista b</li>\
   <li id="My_li_c">lista c</li>\
  ');
  setTimeout('alert($("#My_li_a").text());',100);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="My_Element">
 <li>lista 1</li>
 <li>lista 2</li>
 <li>lista 3</li>
</ul><br>
<button>cambar lista</button>
```

o si prefieres javascript:

```js
function changeList() {
 document.getElementById("My_Element").innerHTML='\
   <li id="My_li_a">lista a</li>\
   <li id="My_li_b">lista b</li>\
   <li id="My_li_c">lista c</li>\
  ';
  setTimeout('alert(document.getElementById("My_li_a").innerHTML);',100);
};
```

```html
<ul id="My_Element">
 <li>lista 1</li>
 <li>lista 2</li>
 <li>lista 3</li>
</ul><br>
<button onClick="changeList()">cambar lista</button>
```

compara este código con el tuyo y encontraras el error, Saludos.. ;))